# Destroy table datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to create a table with jquery datatable, Now i try to destroy table and  when table is display again then want new re iniztaize table

I'm using:

```
 success: function (result) {
         var final = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
                    console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response);
                 $('#tabledata').dataTable().fnDestroy();

 var data_insert = $('#tabledata').DataTable({
                  "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                  "columns": [

                {
                    "title": "RegNo",
                    "data": "RegNo"
                }, {
                    "title": "Owner",
                    "data": "Owner"

                },
                {
                    "title": "D D S B",
                    "data": "D D S B"

                },
                {
                    "title": "D P S B",
                    "data": "D P S B"

                }


                  ]

              });
    for (var i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {

        if (final[i] !== null) {
            $("#tabledata tbody").append("<tr><td>" +
                    final[i][0] + "</td> <td>" +
                    final[i][1] + "</td> <td>" +
                    final[i][2] + "</td> <td>" +
                    final[i][3] + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }

data_insert.draw();

 <table id="tabledata"   cellspacing="0"  class=" inner_table  table-striped table-bordered alltables">
    <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
```

but this is not working and this shows error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 0):

to destroy use below any one

```
$('#tabledata').DataTable.destroy();

$('#tabledata').empty();

$('#tabledata').unbind();
```

Comment: i use table is hide but still pagination ,search, Showing 1 to 10 of 36 entries, and length menu is still display..

Comment: i use table is hide but still pagination ,search, Showing 1 to 10 of 36 entries, and length menu is still display..... if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#tabledata"))
                    {
                        $('#tabledata').dataTable().fnDestroy();     
                    }
                    $('#tabledata tbody > tr').remove();

Comment: please try this $('#tabledata').dataTable().fnDraw();

Comment: why draw.. i want to destroy table.